# MVVM am i implementing this correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been trying to wrap my head around mvvm for the last week or more and still struggling a bit.  I have watched Jason Dolingers MVVM video and gone through Reed Copsey lessons and still find myself wondering if i am doing this right... i created a very simple clock application which i will post below.  The output of the program is as expected however I'm more interested in if I'm actually using the pattern correctly.  Any thoughts comments etc would be appreciated.

my model

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Clock
{
    public class ClockModel
    {
        private const int TIMER_INTERVAL = 50;

        private DateTime _time;

        public event Action<DateTime> TimeArrived;

        public ClockModel()
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GenerateTimes));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            thread.Start();
        }

        public DateTime DateTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _time;
            }
            set
            {
                this._time = value;
                if (TimeArrived != null)
                {
                    TimeArrived(DateTime);
                }
            }
        }

        private void GenerateTimes()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                Thread.Sleep(TIMER_INTERVAL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my view

```
<Window x:Class="Clock.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Clock"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="75" Width="375">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:ClockViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Background="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateTime}" Foreground="White" Background="Black" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

my view model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Clock
{
    public class ClockViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DateTime _time;
        private ClockModel clock;

        public ClockViewModel()
        {
            clock = new ClockModel();
            clock.TimeArrived += new Action<DateTime>(clock_TimeArrived);
        }

        private void clock_TimeArrived(DateTime time)
        {
            DateTime = time;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DateTime");
        }

        public DateTime DateTime 
        {
            get
            {
                return _time;
            }

            set
            {
                _time = value;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a property value changes.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the property changed event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your implementation looks good in terms of separation of concerns although you might be interested in delegating your `Model` method to a `Command` then you could attach it to let's say the `Loaded` event of your main UI. It's definitely a personal preference but as good practice I tend to try to keep a 1:1 relationship between `View`:`ViewModel` and `Model.Method`:`Command`

Comment: hmmm think you lost me there, I will read up on commands and see if i can get a better understanding of what you mean

Comment: sorry about that -- so the idea is to have things as loosely coupled as possible, namely it'd be preferred to implement commanding instead of event handling, that is, not subscribing to the `clock.TimeArrived` event 'directly' but through an implementation of `ICommand` instead

Comment: By any chance could you provide and example sir.  Most of the articles i have read tonight illustrate binding a command to a button but I'm not following how it would replace my event.

Comment: absolutely -- I believe you might find the `EventToCommand` behavior, available on the MVVM Light Toolkit (http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) rather interesting, it allows you to (quoting now) "bind any event of any UI element to an ICommand, for example on the ViewModel, directly in XAML. This makes using Commands much easier, without writing code behind. With the newest version, you can even get the EventArgs of the fired event directly in the ViewModel to handle it."

Answer (score 2):

The way you're doing it is fine. There's just one thing I would change : move the call to `RaisePropertyChange` to the setter of the property. That how it's usually done, and it prevents you from forgetting to raise the notification when you set the property.

Answer (score 0):

For some normal features, using MVVM is quite easily, when you start to touch showing message box. display separate windows, and communication between view and viewmodel.  then you will find something tricky..

Comment: Yes it certainly is, and I have yet to see a good example which shows how to do such a thing in a maintainable and simple manner.  I end up creating a bunch of global data used to communicate between views and I fail to see how that is a good design.  MVVM kinda pisses me off... :D